# Angular ui-select multiple dropdown filter

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have the following list from which I need to create a multiple multi-select dropdown using ui-select

```
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "name":"Return on Equity (IFRS)",
      "type":"profitability",

   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "name":"Return on Assets (IFRS)",
      "type":"profitability",

   },
   {
      "Id":3,
      "name":"EBITDA Margin (IFRS)",
      "type":"profitability",

   },
   {
      "Id":4,
      "name":"EBIT Margin (IFRS)",
      "type":"profitability",

   },
   {
      "Id":5,
      "name":"Net Profit Margin (IFRS)",
      "type":"profitability",

   },
   {
      "Id":8,
      "name":"Cash Ratio",
      "type":"liquidity",

   },
   {
      "Id":9,
      "name":"Quick Ratio",
      "type":"liquidity",

   },
   {
      "Id":10,
      "name":"Current Ratio",
      "type":"liquidity",

   },
   {
      "Id":11,
      "name":"Net Financial Liabilities",
      "type":"debt",

   }
];
```

I need to be able to select multiple "types" in the first dropdown based on which the corresponding "names" should be shown in the second dropdown. I seem to have hit a roadblock with this. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have tried so far. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lbvgpcrq5lrSazpbtsAi?p=preview)

Comment: you asked this question earlier? You should handle this in the angular controller itself. which would be knowing what is the json content is available

Comment: No this is a different question. The JSON structure is the same though.

Comment: But my suggestion is the same. to have the filtering part in your controller

Answer (score 0):

let's use 2 custom filters:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
  return function(collection, keyname) {
    return Object.keys(collection.reduce((res, curr) => {
      res[curr.type] = curr;
      return res;
    }, {}));
  };
});

app.filter('matchType', function() {
  return function(collection, keynames) {
    return collection.filter(item => ~keynames.indexOf(item.type));
  };
});
```

*unique* filter returns an array of strings with unique types and *matchType* filters array by selected types.
HTML:

```
<ui-select multiple 
           ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.type" 
           theme="bootstrap" 
           style="width: 800px;">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select type...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="type in ctrl.people | unique : 'type'">
    <div ng-bind-html="type | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<pre>{{ ctrl.multipleDemo.type | json }}</pre>

<br><br>

<ui-select multiple 
           ng-model="ctrl.multipleDemo.name" 
           ng-disabled="!ctrl.multipleDemo.type.length" 
           theme="bootstrap" 
           style="width: 800px;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select name...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person in ctrl.people | matchType : ctrl.multipleDemo.type">
    <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<pre>{{ ctrl.multipleDemo.name | json }}</pre>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6aqPwuRwoJdHUmvFOquI?p=preview

TODO: when type is removed from the first select, make sure to remove persons with removed type from the second *ng-model*